# Magento 2 : Corn job is not executing

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, xampp, windows

I have created a module which has a `Tests.php` file.

I wanted to run this `execute()` method from `Tests.php` class to be executed once every Day.

I have created a Corn job, But it is `Not Executing` as expected, please check my code and point me where I am missing.

Please let me know how I can call the Method from a

> app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\registration.php

```
<?php /**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register( \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Autosynch_synchProduct',
__DIR__
);
```

> \app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\etc\crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="Autosynch\synchProduct\Cron\Tests" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

> \app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\Cron\Tests.php

```
<?php
namespace Autosynch\synchProduct\Cron;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Tests {
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

/**
   * Write to system.log
   *
   * @return void
   */

    public function execute() {
        $this->logger->info('Cron Works');
    }

}
```

Here is the database snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Please check cron schedule is created in database or not.

Comment: Added the screenshot of the Database  table of Cron Schedule

Comment: Means not running. Right?

Comment: Yes,  Do i need to wait for some time. Any default time is applied before executing ..?

Comment: Please execute `php bin/magento cron:run` from Magento2 root directory.

Comment: Yes, I did this many times..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79083/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-jb-pakalapati).

Comment: Just to confirm, is your crontab file actually called `crontab.xml` and not `corntab.xml` as per your question?

Comment: Yes, it was correct in my code as `crontab.xml`. I misspelt it in the question and corrected now.

Comment: @JBPakalapati have you solved? looking for same